# Create batch file to find a file in C directory(including subdirectories)

Tags: batch-file

Please need some help with this. I am new to scripting..
How to create a batch file to find a file with filename "sample.txt" in C directory(including its subdirectories). If the file found, I want to get the file path in path variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure, there is only one `sample.txt` on your disk? If no, how to decide which is the correct one?

Comment: Sorry, "sample.txt" is an example. It can be something else but it is a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a recursive file search

```
@echo off
    for /d /r c:\ %%a in (sample.txt) do (
        if exist "%%a" set "path=%path%;%%~dpa" & goto endSearch
    )
:endSearch
```

For a WMIC search

```
@echo off

    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('
        wmic datafile where "drive='c:' and filename='sample' and extension='txt'" get name 2^>nul 
        ^| find ":"
    ') do set "path=%path%;%%~dpa" & goto endSearch
:endSearch
```

Note that in both cases it will end the search on the first matching file

Answer (score 1):

This is one way in a batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "c:\sample.txt" /b /s /a-d ') do set "variable=%%~dpa"
```